# Can I cast from an interface to a concrete type with another interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface

I should start by saying that I am very much a noobie with interfaces so this might be a really dumb question.  Also apologies if my Title is unclear - matches the state of my mind!

I do understand the principles behind interfaces and I am want to use them here both to support unit testing and also decoupling via a DI Framework in what is horribly messy and un-testable legacy code.

I have an inteface called IDatHandler.  It has a List<> property called Items.  The concrete implementations should return a concrete type of IDatContainer.  There are some methods of course but I have left them out

```
public interface IDatHandler
{
    ....

   List<IDatContainer> Items
    {
        get; set;
    }

}
```

This is a concrete implementation:

```
public class ADEColorHandler : IDatHandler
    {
      ....

        public List<ADEColor> Items
        {
            get; set;

        }

    }
}
```

ADEColor implements IDatContainer. The concrete implementation fails unless I replace `ADEColor` with `IDatContainer`.

Is there a way to get Items returned as a list of type `ADEColor` or am I just breaking the rules?

I should have said that this app is currently using NET 3.5

**=========>>> The Answer - thanks Charleh!**

The IDatHandler Interface

```
public interface IDatHandler<T> where T : IDatContainer
{
    ....

   List<IDatContainer> Items
    {
        get; set;
    }

}
```

The concrete Class:

```
public class ADEColorHandler : IDatHandler<ADEColor>
        {
          ....

            public List<ADEColor> Items
            {
                get; set;

            }

        }
    }
```

My units tests on ADEColorHandler Assert against this list and pass.

Comment: I want ADEColorHandler to implement the interface IDatHandler but return a list of ADEColor rather than having to return a list of IDatContainer and then have the caller responsible for casting the result.  I know I could do something like that but I would like to know of there is a better way.

Comment: Just checking but the `List<IDatContainer>` should really be `List<T>` - probably just a typo!

Comment: S'all working fine - thanks Charleh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go this route:

```
public interface IDatHandler
{
    // Any common interface stuff
}

public interface IDatHandler<T> : IDatHandler
    where T : IDatContainer
{
    // Any generics
    List<T> Items;
}

public class ADEColorHandler : IDatHandler<ADEColor>
{
  ....

    public List<ADEColor> Items
    {
        get; set;

    }

}
```

This does mean you need to do some casting at the other end though since if you just pass around `IDatHandler` instances, you need to know the generic type before you can query `Items`

What are you trying to achieve? That might help determine what you can use...

Alternatively you could use IEnumerable in your original interface implementation - do you need to know the concrete type of the collection at design time or can you get away with casting?

Edit: added the constraint above

Just trying to get my head round this because using the above interface will work to a certain degree but my assumption is that you want to loop through these to process them etc - I'm wondering if this would work (need to check)

```
List<IDatHandler<IDatContainer>> someList = new List<IDatHandler<IDatContainer>>();
someList.Add((IDatHandler<IDatContainer>)new ADEColorHandler());
```

Then you could enumerate the list... going to just check to see if this works.

Edit: nope, didn't work since the generic type is actually different at runtime. I'll have a mess around - I enjoy trying to work out what you can and can't do with generics!

Edit:

Ok so the best one is probably:

```
    public interface IDatHandler<T> : IDatHandler
        where T : IDatContainer
    {
        List<T> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ADEColorHandler : IDatHandler<IDatContainer>
    {
        public List<IDatContainer> Items
        {
            get;
            set;

        }
    }
```

Which means you can do:

```
var items = new List<IDatHandler<IDatContainer>>();
items.Add(new ADEColorHandler());
```

then you can enumerate and get `Items` from each `IDatHandler` and query each `IDatContainer`. Of course you are hidden from the concrete types but I assume you have an interface on the containers to try and abstract those implementation details. This should be fine

Comment: As to what I am trying to achieve I guess I am trying to learn....  I have a bunch of data files each of which are CSV and different.  The Handlers are all similar except for the content of the data strings.  I am trying to genericize the process as much as possible.

Comment: +1 to this answer. Is there a way to use Covariance or Contravariance while implementing an interface?

Comment: Edited with what I think you need! Let me know if that makes sense