# Cannot cast concrete implementation to constrained type interface of implementation

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, generics, casting, type-constraints

Have a complex visitor scenario with constrained interface:

```
public enum EDTypes { A1, A2 }
public interface IProcing { string doIt(string value); }
public interface IFooIni : IProcing { }
public interface IFooEnd : IProcing { }
public class FooIni_A1 : IFooIni { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_A01"; } }
public class FooEnd_A1 : IFooEnd { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsEnd_A01"; } }
public class FooIni_A2 : IFooIni { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_A02"; } }
public class FooEnd_A2 : IFooEnd { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsEnd_A02"; } }
public interface IFooSet<H, T> : IProcing
    where H : IFooIni
    where T : IFooEnd
{
    H FooIni { get; set; }
    List<IProcing> FooBar { get; set; }
    T FooEnd { get; set; }
}
```

and multiples concrete implementations:

```
public class FooSet_A1 : IFooSet<FooIni_A1, FooEnd_A1>
{
    public FooIni_A1 FooIni { get; set; }
    public List<IProcing> FooBar { get; set; }
    public FooEnd_A1 FooEnd { get; set; }
    public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_FooSetA1"; }
}
public class FooSet_A2 : IFooSet<FooIni_A2, FooEnd_A2>
{
    public FooIni_A2 FooIni { get; set; }
    public List<IProcing> FooBar { get; set; }
    public FooEnd_A2 FooEnd { get; set; }
    public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_FooSetA2"; }
}
```

why cant do:

```
public class testfoo
{
    private IFooSet<IFooIni, IFooEnd> getInstance(EDTypes type)
    {
        IFooSet<IFooIni, IFooEnd> res = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case EDTypes.A1:
                /*
                    Unable to cast object of type 
                    '_protoTest.FooSet_A1' 
                    to type 
                    '_protoTest.IFooSet`2[_protoTest.IFooIni,_protoTest.IFooEnd]'.
                */
                res = (IFooSet<IFooIni, IFooEnd>)new FooSet_A1();
                break;
            case EDTypes.A2:
                res = (IFooSet<IFooIni, IFooEnd>)new FooSet_A2();
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }
    public void testIt()
    {
        // +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
        IFooSet<IFooIni, IFooEnd> A1 = (IFooSet<IFooIni, IFooEnd>)getInstance(EDTypes.A1);
        string x = A1.doIt("ASDFG");
        // +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
    }
}
```

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723437/can-i-cast-from-an-interface-to-a-concrete-type-with-another-interface-implement) telling to create another interface above, but I need the problematic interface structure on my factory result.

---

@Eldritch Conundrum told me about "covariance on T" and helped me a 
lot get what is happening.
I cant get yet a solution to this problem and getting crazy with the deadline
but my question was "why" its happening and he explained very well.
Putting more detail. Marking as answer.

### Thanks a lot

After last coment of @Eldritch Conundrum i used dynamic keyword and solved my problem.
I losted all intellisense but its work now !!!
Thanks @Eldritch Conundrum
There is the code :

```
*public enum EDTypes { A1, A2 }
public interface IProcing { string doIt(string value); }
public interface IFooIni : IProcing { }
public interface IFooEnd : IProcing { }
public class FooIni_A1 : IFooIni { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_A01"; } }
public class FooEnd_A1 : IFooEnd { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsEnd_A01"; } }
public class FooIni_A2 : IFooIni { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_A02"; } }
public class FooEnd_A2 : IFooEnd { public string doIt(string value) { return "itsEnd_A02"; } }
public interface IFooSet<H, T> : IProcing
    where H : IFooIni
    where T : IFooEnd
{
    H FooIni { get; set; }
    List<IProcing> FooBar { get; set; }
    T FooEnd { get; set; }
}
public class FooSet_A1 : IFooSet<FooIni_A1, FooEnd_A1>
{
    public FooIni_A1 FooIni { get; set; }
    public List<IProcing> FooBar { get; set; }
    public FooEnd_A1 FooEnd { get; set; }
    public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_FooSetA1"; }
}
public class FooSet_A2 : IFooSet<FooIni_A2, FooEnd_A2>
{
    public FooIni_A2 FooIni { get; set; }
    public List<IProcing> FooBar { get; set; }
    public FooEnd_A2 FooEnd { get; set; }
    public string doIt(string value) { return "itsIni_FooSetA2"; }
}
public class testfoo
{
    private IProcing getInstance(EDTypes type)
    {
        dynamic res = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case EDTypes.A1:
                res = new FooSet_A1();
                break;
            case EDTypes.A2:
                res = new FooSet_A2();
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }
    public void testIt()
    {
        // +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
        dynamic A1 = getInstance(EDTypes.A1);
        string s1 = A1.doIt("ASDFG");
        dynamic A2 = getInstance(EDTypes.A2);
        string s2 = A2.doIt("ASDFG");
        // +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
    }
}*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to convert an `IConstrained<CtrA1, CtrB1, CtrC1>` to an `IConstrained<IClassA, IClassB, IClassC>` because `CtrA1` implements `IClassA` (and similarly for the others).

This is a bit like converting an `IEnumerable<string>` to an `IEnumerable<object>`.

.Net allows it because `IEnumerable<T>` is actually declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`. This called **covariance** on T.

However, this won't work for you if your `IConstrained<>` has methods that take an `IClassA`, because that would be unsafe. Can you see why?

Casting an `IEnumerable<string>` to an `IEnumerable<object>` is safe because one can only ever read strings/objects from `IEnumerable`.
But for a `List<T>`, it wouldn't work, because a `List<string>` casted into a `List<object>` would enable you to add an object into the list (of strings!).

Comment: thanks a lot for your atenttion and help. 
There is more detail now and i tried the "out" keyword but its dont fit my case, i need use the type inside.

Comment: Im probably wrong and cant question or do anything about it with my small view about this topic, but IMHO a language maker disallowing me put a set of cats on a variable of type animal because is afraid that i will try insert a fish on cat set packaged as set of animal sound crazy to me, is my responsability dont put fish togheter cats on the set, its minimal expected, like dont divide by zero or dont call method on a null instance class.  
Covariance ties my hands and takes off me helpful possibilities , it's like a  strait-gallows for programmers.

Comment: There is some way to disable it ?

Comment: With the question as it stands now that you have modified it, I can't tell if I really understand your problem. Covariance is not your enemy here, rather it is just the soundness of C#'s static typing. You can't globally disable static typing, if that's what you want you should be using a dynamically-typed language such as ruby, python or javascript. Or maybe you can make use of the 'dynamic' keyword, but I'm not sure if it fits in your case.

Comment: your dynamic keyword  fit in the case and helped me a lot !! I losted the intellisense but no problem, happy for it working now. Less crazy with my deadline now. I put new code in my question text above.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Reading your new code, it seems like the only thing you do with `IFooSet` is, you call `doIt()`... That means you could just use `IProcing` instead of `dynamic` as a return type of `getInstance()`. The real problem would be, if you tried to use `FooIni` or `FooEnd` on your `IFooSet`.